# How to format a response to have columns and rows in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an  API response and return the following format.

```
AccountId Requests
1         3
2         67
3         50
          10
-- 10 batches, 10 datasources
```

However, when I added this response to an empty array, it changed to the below format.How can I change the format in the array to columns and rows?

```
["\e[1mAccountId    requests    \n\e[m1    3    \n2    67    \n3    50    \n    9.   \n-- 10 batches, 10 datasource\n"]
```

Comment: do you have control over the API response format? I don't know what syntax is being used here. It's not javascript. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Yes, I use something like SQL query to store the data in to table format. That is the reason the response return in a table format. @LesNightingill

Comment: you need to return the data in a format that is more useful! I'm not sure what's appropriate, b/c you haven't shared how the data is generated or structured. It should be a json format that can be understood by JSON.parse(response) in the view.

Comment: you should also post the expected format of your data